# resolve VMs to subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have a dedicated server which has only one public IP address (eg.10.20.30.40) and a domain dedicated to it (example.com)

on that server I have lots of virtual machines hosted on an ESXi Hypervisor, and each vm does a different job (mail server, chat server, file server, etc). each vm took a local IP from my DNS-vm DHCP.

**How can I resolve each vm local to a subdomain?**

I think putting a vm acting as a DNS server in front could resolve ALL requests to a vm, but I don't know how. please see my server internal network topology:

[image: network-topo.jpg]

for example if someone sends request to mail.example.com, his request will reach DNS first and DNS routes all traffic (forward and backward) to specific vm (192.168.1.10)

Comment: Do you mean that all servers should be resolvade on a subdomain on the local network or for the entire world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they weren't all heterogeneous I would suggest a load balancer. But because you're largely running http servers I would use a single NGINX box to reverse proxy back to the service. You can then forward port 25 (or whatever your mail server uses) manually

> When using the Nginx web server, server blocks (similar to the virtual hosts in Apache) can be used to encapsulate configuration details and host more than one domain off of a single server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/